# How can I print an Excel sheet summary for each row in a single page?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

I have an Excel sheet like in this example

[image: example 1]

Each row (labeled "Name n") is a person and the columns are the data related to it (Data 1, Data 2, etc., until "COD"). What I need to do is to print a single page for each person containing its data. Referring to the example above, I need to get something like in the below example, repeated for each row (person) and I would like to be able to set the page layout as needed.

[image: example 2]

How can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Your easiest way is probably to use mail merge option of Word, there you can set up your template and automatically fill the data from Excel, one page per row. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-mail-merge-to-create-and-send-bulk-mail-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705 and https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose this is a valid question, without knowing Excel it's really difficult to find the good direction.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose You are right, but Excel and Word are, at least for me, two of a series of extremely large softwares where even the smallest task might be a bit difficult if you have never done it before. What I asked was just a cue from where to start.

Comment: Infact as @MátéJuhász suggested, mail merge is the solution I was looking for. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comment, the right tool for you is to use Word's mail merge feature (official help [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-mail-merge-to-create-and-send-bulk-mail-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705) and [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3)).

There you can set up a template, then fill it with data from Excel, one page from each row.